# webRTC - pushing stream through webAudio gainNode keeps mic engaged even after call hangup

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

I have below pieces of code

```
function modifyGain(stream){
    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var ctx = new AudioContext();

  var src = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  var dst = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();

  var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
  gainNode.gain.value = 3.5;
  src.connect(gainNode);

  gainNode.connect(dst);
 
  return dst.stream;
}
```

I tried `addTrack()` and `removeTrack()` on original stream but no luck.

This is how use that function above.

```
webcamStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
webcamStream = modifyGain(webcamStream);

document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = webcamStream;

webcamStream.getTracks().forEach(
        function (track){
            myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, webcamStream);
        });
```

This is how I stop the tracks on call hangup

```
webcamStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
            track.stop();
        });
webcamStream = null;
localVideo.srcObject = null;
```

All works fine before I apply that gain related code. But once I add that the browsers don't release mic and I have to refresh the page in order to have any audio exchange with other end.

Please help.

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/fL5adw69/

Comment: I am unable to reproduce using your fiddle too.

Comment: I tried below given code and it seems to work. But I am not sure is it good way to do it or no. `preGainLocalStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
  webcamStream = modifyGain(preGainLocalStream);`

Then I stopped `webcamStream` and `preGainLocalStream` using the `preGainLocalStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
   track.stop();
  });` and same for the other stream.

Answer (score 0):

There are two streams. You're only stopping the tracks in the second stream, the one created by `ctx.createMediaStreamDestination()`.

To relinquish the microphone, you instead need to stop the tracks in the original stream obtained from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.